# How to allow Guest checkout (with Django and dj-stripe)

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I have a Django project that accepts payments using the dj-stripe app, as long as the customer is logged in, or creates an account.  I would like to provide a way for customers to check out as a guest, without registering - like most online stores allow.

I am thinking about using django-lazysignup, or creating a 'guest' user that all the transactions would use.

Am I on the right track, or is there a better pattern for guest checkouts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing the dj-stripe package requires is an email address to link a local user to a Stripe customer. If you just ask for an email address on guest checkout, make email addresses unique in your system, and create your own views, I don't see you running into any implementation issues.